# Vertical Text in button look neat

Tags: html, css

I have a div(which I want to look like a button) and I am displaying the text in it vertically. I want the text to look neat. How can I do it? [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6v2Cm/1/)

```
    <div id="btn-toggle-menu">Hide Menu</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #btn-toggle-menu {
       position:fixed;
       width:10.9px;
       line-height:25px;
       cursor:pointer;
       border:1px solid #333;
       background-color:#ccc;
       text-align:center;
       font-weight:bold;
       font-size:20px;
       word-wrap: break-word;
   }
```

Comment: Define neat. This is a site for programming questions, not design questions, so unless you can show us an image of how you want it to look, we can't really help you.

Comment: Isn't "neat" strongly oppinion based?

Comment: Now it is like H i d e M e n u(vertically). I want to display it as Hide Menu(vertically)

Comment: You should set line-height accordingly.

Comment: Do you want to rotate the chars?

Comment: @C-Link setting line height doesnt make the letters look like words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/29/)

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu">H
 i
 d
 e

 M
 e
 n
 u
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #btn-toggle-menu {
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:20px;
      cursor:pointer;
      border:1px solid #333;
      background-color:#ccc;
      text-align:center;
      white-space: pre;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, your problem solved. try this

**HTML:**

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu">
    <div style="width:10px;">
        Hide Menu
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#btn-toggle-menu {
    position:fixed;
    width:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left:8px;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6v2Cm/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use the width = 1em (one width of letter M) and use white-space in pre-mode:

```
#btn-toggle-menu {
    text-align: center;
    width:1em;
    word-wrap: pre;
}
```

Text is aligned to the center.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6v2Cm/5/